# Consumer Class Listener method not getting triggered to receive messages from topic. Kafka with Spring Boot App

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Kafka with Spring Boot. I use Rest Controllers to call Producer/Consumer API's. Producer Class is able to add messages to the topic. I verified using command line utility (Console-consumer.sh). However my Consumer class is not able to receive them in Java for further processing.
@KafkaListener used in Consumer class listener method should be able to receive messages when my Producer class posts messages to the topic which is not happening. Any help appreciated.

Is it still necessary for consumer to subscribe and poll for records when I have already created KafkaListenerContainerFactory that is responsible for invoking Consumer Listener method when a message is posted to the topic?

**Consumer Class**

```java
@Component
public class KafkaListenersExample {

    private final List<KafkaPayload> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    @KafkaListener(topics = "test_topic", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void listener(KafkaPayload data) {
        synchronized (messages){
            messages.add(data);
        }
        //System.out.println("message from kafka :"+data);
    }

    public List<KafkaPayload> getMessages(){
        return messages;
    }
}
```

**Consumer Config**

```java
@Configuration
class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    private String bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";
 

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, KafkaPayload> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props) ;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, KafkaPayload> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, KafkaPayload> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerConfigs());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The listener container creates the consumer, subscribes, and takes care of the polling.

Turning on DEBUG logging should help determine what's wrong.

If the records are already in the topic, you need to set `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` to `earliest`. Otherwise, the consumer starts consuming from the end of the topic (`latest`).

Comment: Adding Offset to the Consumer property made no difference. Still unable to get messages in Listener class.

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging; it should help you figure out what's happening.

Comment: In case of String we use StringSerializer and StringDeserializer but if we plan to use custom classes like POJO, how do we Deserialize/Serialize

Comment: I see you are new here; don't ask unrelated questions in comments; ask a new question. You simply need to configure the producer and consumer properties to use your (de)serializer.

Comment: Hi Gary, I would like to clarify it's not a new/unrelated question. I have a POJO class which I have configured in my Producer Configuration to receive the JSON data from a Rest Call. But same Configuration for Consumer doesn't seem to work. I have used JsonDeserializer instead of StringDeserialzer since I have the requirement to work with JSON unlike plane text/String. Any help appreciated

Comment: Your original question was about not receiving messages; I told you DEBUG logging should help you figure out what's wrong. Now you are asking about how to use a deserializer; which is unrelated. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#serdes). If you still have questions, ask a new one.